# How can I include an ID to submit in a form associated with one of the text fields?

Tags: php, html, jquery-ui, spotify

I have a PHP web page (`new_item.php`) containing an HTML form to create a new "item," which is in my case band merchandise. The four inputs are artist name, item type, item photos, and item description. I'm using the Spotify Web API on a separate PHP script (`search_artists.php`) to search for artists on Spotify with a name similar to the one provided.

New Item Form:
[image]

When I click on one of the autocomplete options, not only do I want to have it complete the artist name, but I want that **artist's Spotify UID to be included** somewhere in the form so I can use that ID when the form is submitted. Right now my `search_artists.php` only outputs an array of artist names similar to the one provided to it. For example-

If I visit `search_artists.php?name=weez`, the page gives me the following:

```
["Lil Wayne","Weezer","Lich Weezy","D-weezy","Prince Weez"]
```

So my question has a couple parts-

1. How should I change/format the `search_artists.php` to include both the artist name and the artist Spotify UID? I think I'd have to return a JSON object instead of an array?
2. Using the jQuery UI autocomplete functionality, how can I include the artist name and the artist ID but have the artist ID hidden and insert that Spotify UID inside my form when the autocomplete option is selected so it gets submitted along with the rest of the form data? From what I can tell I will have to use an input tag with `type="hidden"`?

Autocomplete snippet from `new_item.php`

```
$("input#item_artist").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.get("search_artists.php", {
                name: encodeURIComponent(request.term)
            }, function(data) {
                console.log("request.term = " + request.term + "\ndata (" + typeof data + ") = " + data);
                response(JSON.parse(data));
            })
        },
        appendTo: "#artist_suggestions"
    });
```

`search_artists.php`

```
include '../resources/includes/init.php'; 

if (isset($_GET["name"])) {
    $name = "*" . urldecode($_GET["name"]) . "*";
    $artists = search_artist($name);
//    output($artists);
    $results = array();
    if (is_array($artists) || is_object($artists)) {
        foreach ($artists as $artist) {
            if (!in_array($artist->name, $results))
                $results[] = $artist->name; // $artist also has an id field
        }
        echo json_encode($results);
    } else {
        echo "[]";
    }
} else {
    ?>
    <form action="search_artists.php" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" />
    </form>
    <?php
}
```

Any pointers in the right direction or any suggestions at all are appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I would suggest you to use JQuery: Select2 plugin instead: http://select2.org